# Method ResetPasswordController::reset does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, reset-password

Why I got this problem ?

ResetPasswordController::reset does not exist

```php
trait ResetsPasswords{

public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        ......

    }
}
```

Comment: does your `ResetPassowordController` use the `ResetsPasswords` trait?

Comment: @lagbox , yes! but Why so that?

Comment: if the controller was using that trait it would have that method

Comment: @lagbox these method: $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessage());
        
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        
            $this->credentials($request), function($user, $password){
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);

Comment: that `reset` method in on the password broker ... if you have an actual error message with stack add it to your question above

Comment: @lagbox Can you help again ? thanks for teach me!

Comment: i really can't without more information ... out of the box this all works fine ... we would need the error stack trace

Comment: @lagbox ok, thanks I will do it again